# Contact form submit error

Tags: php, html, forms, contacts

I've got a simple contact form set up, but am having a little trouble with the finishing touches. I'm getting an error message whenever the form is submitted. Was hoping someone can take a look at my code and point out my mistake. Thanks!

(edited) Forgot to mention the error is that once form is submitted, I am being redirected to the error page (error.html) instead of the success (contactthanks.php) page.

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="contactengine.php">
<label for="Name">Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" />

<label for="City">City:</label>
<input type="text" name="City" id="City" />

<label for="Email">Email:</label>
<input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" />

<label for="Message">Message:</label><br />
<textarea name="Message" rows="20" cols="20" id="Message"></textarea>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-button" />
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

$EmailFrom = "";
$EmailTo = "MYEMAIL@gmail.com";
$Subject = "";
$Name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Name'])); 
$Tel = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Tel'])); 
$Email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email'])); 
$Message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Message'])); 


$validationOK=true;
if (!$validationOK) {
print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.html\">";
exit;
}


$Body = "";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $Name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Tel: ";
$Body .= $Tel;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $Email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $Message;
$Body .= "\n";


$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");

if ($success){
print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=contactthanks.php\">";
}
else{
print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.html\">";
}
?>
```

Comment: What is the error you get from this?

Comment: i think you just give the same name to the variables and input types. try with different names. like $name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Name']));
smaill 'name' instead of capital 'Name'.
hope it help.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention. Instead of going to my success (contactthanks.php) page, it is redirecting to the error page (error.html) on submit.

Answer (score 1):

```
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");

if ($success){
print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=contactthanks.php\">";
}
else{
print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.html\">";
}
```

It is redirecting to your error page because the call to `mail` is returning `false` (indicating the email was not accepted for delivery) and that is exactly what you are telling it to do in that situation.

You need to check the SMTP set up on your server.

Typically the settings to check for are `sendmail_from` and `sendmail_path` in your PHP.ini file. Seeing as you are already setting a `From` header, `sendmail_path` is likely to not be set up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

See what's causing the problem with

```
ini_set("display_errors", "1"); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);`.
```

My guess is you have wrong smtp settings and `mail` function fails.